# How to prevent mouse leave event when hovering over checkbox

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I have a form with the panel, which will have some checkboxes for options. I made panel slide in to the form when mouse hovers the edge of it (edge of panel). I made it hide (slide back) when mouse leaves the panel. The problem is that when I point a checkbox in this panel a mouseleave event occures and panel slides back so I cannot check checkbox. Is there any way to prevent mouseleave event when mouse is still over the panel and some checkboxes in it? My idea for know is to make a condition based on mouse pointer position in mouseleave event, but I hope that there is a way to make app treat a checkbox as a part of panel. Did not put any food since it is not problem of it. But can post if needed.

Comment: you could attach the CheckBox MouseOvers to the same handler

Comment: See [How can a hover effect be created for a grouping of controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6672318/719186)

Comment: @sa_ddam213 how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that the `mouseleave` event of the checkbox triggers `mouseleave` event of the panel due to the event bubbling. You can read more about event bubbling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing).

To prevent the event bubbling, attach `mouseleave` event on the checkboxes and call `event.stopPropagation()`. 
Sample code with jQuery:

```
$("checkboxes_selector").on("mouseleave", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am begginer and did not work with jQuery yet. But I'll look into that.