# C#: How to MouseHover on a group of objects and MouseLeave event when you leave the entire group

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a few objects in a groupBox in Visual Studio such as a few buttons. I have a label that pops up when I enter the groupBox and disappears when I leave it. However, when I hover over a button in this groupBox, the label disappears as the MouseLeave event only corresponds to the groupBox.

Is there anyway to have all of these objects grouped together so when I hover on anything in the groupBox the label stays and when I leave the groupBox altogether the label disappears? I just want an elegant way to do this.

Thanks so much for your help!

This is different than [How can a hover effect be created for a grouping of controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671708/how-can-a-hover-effect-be-created-for-a-grouping-of-controls) because I'd like a different result than what this person wants and also I tried something similar and it didn't work.

Comment: Add the same `event` to all the children of the `groupBox`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not add objects by groupbox but you can add them as a list of the control type of itself.

here you go.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox[] textboxes = new TextBox[] { textBox1 , textBox2, textBox3 };
        Button[] buttons = new Button[] { button1 };

        foreach (TextBox tbox in textboxes)
        {
            tbox.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(textbox_MouseEnter);
            tbox.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(textbox_MouseLeave);
        }

        foreach (var button in buttons)
        {
            button.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(btn_MouseEnter);
            button.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(btn_MouseLeave);
        }
    }

    private void btn_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var Button = (Button)sender;
        button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        //label show
    }

    private void btn_MouseLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var Button = (Button)sender;
        button1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        //label hide
    }

    private void textbox_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = (TextBox)sender;
        textbox.BackColor = Color.Red;
        //label show
    }

    private void textbox_MouseLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = (TextBox)sender;
        textbox.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        //label hide
    }
```

GIF IMAGE OF WORKING : [GIF](https://gyazo.com/56d064e43205442dfeb501f6dc0cea7c)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```
        //Add new event handlers on appropriate location in your code (perhaps in the load event of the form?)
        groupBox1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(MouseEnteredGroupBox);
        groupBox1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(MouseLeftGroupBox);
```

In the MouseEnter event handler you change the state of your controls which you want to show.

```
    private void MouseEnteredGroupBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add controls to be shown when entering the groupbox
        button1.Visible = true;
    }
```

Add this method to check if your cursor is inside of your groupbox area

```
    private bool IsAboveGroupBox(GroupBox gb)
    {
        Point cursorPos = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        bool resultX = (cursorPos.X > gb.Location.X && cursorPos.X < gb.Location.X + gb.Size.Width) ? true : false;
        bool resultY = (cursorPos.Y > gb.Location.Y && cursorPos.Y < gb.Location.Y + gb.Size.Height) ? true : false;

        return resultX && resultY;
    }
```

Finally in the MouseLeave event handler you call the method

```
    private void MouseLeftGroupBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsAboveGroupBox(sender as GroupBox))
        {
            //Add controls to be hidden when leaving the groupbox
            button1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Else you could just view your controls on the MouseEnter event on groupbox and hide your controls on the Forms MouseEnter event?

Comment: I get this error for Point cursorPos = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Point' to 'SS.Point'

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. However, When I hover off a label in the groupbox (it's exactly on the edge of the groupbox) it doesn't trigger the mouseleave event even though this label is a child of the groupbox.